# htaccess rewrite url with query string breaks

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I tried to rewrite an url from `http://project2.local/camera?camera_id=1` to `http://project2.local/camera/1` in `.htaccess`... Now every time I add the .htaccess lines:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# Here we rewrite the camera link
# RewriteRule ^camera/([^/]*)$ /camera?camera_id=$1 [L]


# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /camera\.php\?camera_id=([^\&\ ]+)
# RewriteRule ^/?camera\.php$ /camera/%1? [L,R=301]

# specific rule
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]+)=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(camera)$ /camera.php?camera_id=$1 [L]
```

I get the error `Notice: Undefined index: camera_id`. Now I just try to GET the query string, but it doesn't work, like never?

What causes this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect and rewrite url from http://project2.local/camera?camera_id=1 to http://project2.local/camera/1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /camera\.php\?camera_id=([^\&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^/?camera\.php$ /camera/%1? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^camera/([^/]*)$ /camera.php?camera_id=$1 [L]
#remove. php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: That returns the same issue. On line `4`, which has the following code: `$camera_id = $_GET["camera_id"];`

Comment: Well, if the uri `/camera/1` is taking you to `/camera.php` this means that the RewriteRule is ok. Problem might be in your php script.

Comment: Try adding this line at the top of your htaccess `Options -Multiviews` .

Comment: That gives the same result, if I do a var_dump on the `$_GET`, it returns an empty array?

Comment: Do you have any other rules in htaccess?

Comment: Same output, an empty `$_GET` :/

Comment: My bad, I misplaced the .htacces haha